# How to Elegantly Pass All Attributes of a Class as Arguments in a Function?

Tags: python, function, class, properties, setter

I have a somewhat complex class `Thing`, and an associated mixin `IterMixin` (to make the class iterable)...and a `funky` method elsewhere in the codebase which receives an instance of my class as an argument.

In fact, I'm attempting to bundle up a bunch of parameters as single object to be passed to *multiple* external functions beyond the `funky` function below. A parameter object design pattern of sorts...

```
class IterMixin():
    def __iter__(self):
        for attr, value in self.__dict__.items():
            yield attr, value

class Thing(IterMixin):
    def __iter__(self, foo=None, bar=None, baz=999):

        if foo is None:
            self.foo = {}
        else:
            self.foo = foo

        if bar is None:
            self.foo = {}
        else:
            self.bar = bar

        self.baz = baz

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, data)
        self._foo = self.parser(data)

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._bar

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, more_data)
        self._bar, self.baz = self.another_parser(more_data)

    def parser(self, data):
        ...do stuff...
        return foo

    def another_parser(self, more_data):
        ...do add'l stuff...
        return bar, baz
```

With regard to the `funky` function, in a completely different module, via the `Thing` class, I want to pass `Thing`'s attributes (`foo`, `bar`, and `baz`) to the `funky` function as *one argument*...like so:

```
    thing_args = Thing()

    def funky(*thing_args):
        ...do stuff...
        ...expecting to manipulate keys from things_arg
        ...
        return whatever
```

PROBLEM:

If I do not make the *setters* for the attributes `foo` and `bar` *private* (for example, via `self._foo`)--i.e., by way of an underscore--then I evoke  infinite recursion during class initialization ...as the `__init__` and setters for these attributes loop over and over and repeatedly call themselves. To avoid that, I used the`@property` decorator and "privatized" the foo and bar while setting them.

However, when I pass an instance of the `Thing` class, and unpack its attributes as args in the `funky` function via a splat or asterick, if I introspect the resultant keys for those attributes, I still get `_foo` and `_bar`. I can't seem to get rid of the underscores. (In other words, I get the "privatized" attribute names of `Thing`.)

The biz logic of `funky` needs the unpacked values to not have any underscores.

Why is this happening (the underscores upon unpacking)? How can I fix this? Is there a more elegant way to either initialize the foo and bar attributes without privatizing anything? Or perhaps a more Pythonic way to pass all the attributes in the `Thing` class to my `funky` function?

Comment: I think you are really overthinking this whole thing... But it looks like you are having fun, so I won't complain.

Comment: why dont you just pass "thing" ? and use its attributes?

Comment: If you want to be able to pass an instance as if it were a sequence of its attributes, why not just make it a sequence, or at least an iterable? See `namedtuple` in the stdlib for an example (although you don’t need to build anything that complicated).

Comment: Meanwhile, if you’re looking for how to hide private attributes from even determined introspection, you’re just using the wrong language. Python “private” just means “private by convention”.

Comment: You mean the attributes of **instances** of class `Thing`, right?

Comment: @abarnert I agree...but the biz requirement was: "Make this a class and put it in its own module." I've also considered recasting the instance as an OrderedDict (knowing all dicts in the most recent release of Python retain their order anyway). NamedTuple seems like a reasonable option. But...nonetheless...I need to make a _class_ via the client's request. And: it's an interesting problem (to me). Also, yes...I quote "privatize" because I know the underscore and dunder are merely convention. Finally--YES..._instances_ of class Thing.

Comment: @Sean OK, I thought you were asking how to hide your private variables even from yourself. Now I have some more idea of what you're trying to do, and where your confusion is, so I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you've got a major problem that will prevent you from even seeing the problem you've asked for help with: Your `Thing` class defines an `__iter__` method that doesn't `super`, and doesn't `yield` or `return` anything. Hopefully that part is just some typo and you know how to fix it to do whatever you actually wanted there.

No, onto the problem you're asking about:

```
class IterMixin():
    def __iter__(self):
        for attr, value in self.__dict__.items():
            yield attr, value
```

Try printing out the `__dict__` of your instances. Or, better, instances of a minimal example like this:

```
class Thing:
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo
    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, data):
        self._foo = data

t = Thing()
t.foo = 2
print(t.__dict__)
```

The output is `{'_foo': 2}`.

You've tried to hide the attributes by giving them private names and putting them behind properties, but then you've gone around behind the properties' backs and looked directly into the `__dict__` where the real attributes are.

And what else *could* be there? Your actual `_foo` has to be stored *somewhere* on each instance. That `foo`, on the other hand, isn't really a value, it's a getter/setter that uses that private attribute, so it isn't stored anywhere.

If you really want to use reflection to find all of the "public values" on an instance, you can do something like this:

```
for attr, value in inspect.getmembers(self):
    if not attr.startswith('_') and not callable(value):
        yield attr, value
```

However, I think it would be much better to *not* do this reflectively. Simpler and cleaner options include:

- Add a `_fields = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'` and have the base class iterate `_fields_`.
- Write a decorator that registers a property, and have the base class iterate that registry.
- Build something that lets you specify the attributes more declaratively and writes the boilerplate for you. See [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), [`dataclass`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/), and [`attrs`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrs) for some inspiration.
- Just use `attrs` (or, if you're not the OP but someone reading this from the future who can rely on 3.7+, `dataclass`) to do that work for you.
- Rethink your design. A class whose instances iterate name-value pairs of their public attributes is weird in the first place. A "parameter object" that acted like a mapping to be used for keyword-splatting could be useful; one that acted like a normal iterable could be useful; one that acts as an iterable of name-value pairs is useless for anything except for passing to a `dict` construct (at which point it's, again, simpler to be a mapping). Plus, a mixin is really not helping you with the hard part of doing it. [Whatever you actually need to do, ask for help on how to do that, instead of how to make this code that shouldn't work work anyway.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thank you! Super helpful. Was unfamiliar with both the dataclass in v3.7+ and unfamiliar with attrs. The latter did the trick via the _attrs_post_init_ method. Also...thanks for turning me onto the X, Y Problem. Glad to have the vocab to know identify a widespread problem...of which, occasionally, I myself manifest.